# I want to fire the event whenver i add new document to Shared Doc Library

Tags: event-receivers

I have created event receiver, and now i want to add the event whenever the new document is added to shared document library. Which event should i write?(ItemAdded or ItemUpdated)

Thanks.

Element.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListUrl="Shared Documents">
    <Receiver>
      <Name>SharedDocPermissionItemAdded</Name>
      <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
      <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
       <Class>SharedDocPermssionForNewDoc_ER.SharedDocPermission.SharedDocPermission</Class>
  <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
</Receiver>
```

Comment: New document should be ItemAdded. ItemUpdated will only fire on existing documents.

Comment: On ItemAdded is not working.. Before i have tried ItemUpdated,it was working.. But now that is also not working

Comment: Have you tried ItemAdding? You should add what you are trying to accomplish in your question to get a more clear answer.

Comment: My question is clear.. i just want to add a new document and on adding a new document, event should be fire. But ItemAdded is not working

Comment: Well, i think you just answered your own question. You are saying adding a new document, and then the event should be ItemAdding that fires before the document is added, while ItemAdded fires afterwards when the document already has been uploaded.

Comment: It doesn't help to say ItemAdded is "not working". What does that mean? Are you getting error messages? Have you tried debugging with break points etc.? How do you know the event is actually being fired? You need to provide more information for us to be able to help you.

Comment: @Submits: Yes, I tried to debug with break points.. but break points aren't getting initiated. That means its not working. And feature is also activated for event receiver.

Comment: Did you originally create an ItemUpdating event receiver and then change the same event receiver to an ItemAdded one? Or did you create a new ItemAdded event receiver? Check that you are targeting the correct document library. Please share your elements.xml and event receiver code.

Answer (score 1):

`ItemAdded` will fire AFTER the document is ADDED/UPLOADED.

`ItemUpdating` will fire BEFORE the document is UPDATED/EDITED/CHANGED.

In your case it sounds like you need `ItemAdded`.

EDIT:

You have since added your event receiver's elements.xml. I can see you're missing the closing tags at the end: `</Receivers></Elements>`

You also say you initially tried `ItemUpdating`, which fired correctly. Then you tried `ItemAdded` and it didn't fire. I think you tried to change the originally created event receiver and didn't change it properly.

So you should create a fresh new `ItemAdded` event receiver and DO NOT try changing it to `ItemUpdating` or anything else. If you want a different event receiver, it is best to create a new one if you are not 100% sure on how to change an existing one.

If this still does not fire then share both the elements.xml and the event receiver code.